# Operator '&' is not defined for string "Insert into Table_Name(XYZ_" and type 'Byte()'

Tags: vb.net, image, byte, photo

I get this error →

> Operator '&' is not defined for string "Insert into SP_Master_Entry (SP_" and type 'Byte()'.

I think this error is caused near `dr(SP_Photo)` and am very much new to VB.NET

```
mainModule.DatabaseNonQuery("
    Insert into SP_Master_Entry 
     (SP_ID, SP_Name, Gender, Date_Of_Birth, Date_Of_Join, Branch_ID,
      SP_Area_ID, SP_Address1, SP_Address2, SP_Address3, PIN, Qualification,
      Contact_Number, SP_Photo, SP_Status, Caste, SHG_Member, Marital_Status,
      Salary, KYC_TYPE_ID, KYC_Code, Reference, Reference2, Agreement, Resigned,
      ResignedDate,delivery_status,allow_edit) 

    VALUES (" & dr("SP_ID") & ",'" & dr("SP_Name") & "','" & dr("Gender") & "','" 
      & dr("Date_Of_Birth") & "','" & dr("Date_Of_Join") & "'," 
      & dr("Branch_ID") & "," & dr("SP_Area_ID") & ",'" & dr("SP_Address1") 
      & "','" & dr("SP_Address2") & "','" & dr("SP_Address3") & "'," 
      & dr("PIN") & "," & dr("Qualification") & ",'" & dr("Contact_Number")
      & "'," & dr("SP_Photo") & ",'" & dr("SP_Status") & "','" & dr("Caste") 
      & "','" & dr("SHG_Member") & "','" & dr("Marital_Status") & "','" 
      & dr("Salary") & "'," & dr("KYC_TYPE_ID") & ",'" & dr("KYC_Code") 
      & "','" & dr("Reference") & "','" & dr("Reference2") & "','"
      & dr("Agreement") & "','" & dr("Resigned") & "','" & dr("ResignedDate") 
      & "','" & dr("delivery_status") & "','" & dr("allow_edit") & "','" 
      & Today.Date.ToString & "','" & Today.Date.ToString & "')")
```

Comment: A little effort to format better your code will be very appreciated

Comment: Thanks Konard Rudolph for editing the code
Am new to Stack overflow

Answer (score 1):

The error says it all: `Byte()` (i.e. an array of bytes) is a fundamentally different type from `String` and you cannot concatenate the two. How to solve this depends on what data these bytes contain and what you want to get from them. The [`Encoding.GetString` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc.aspx) *may* help, *if* the bytes contain encoded text data.

More generally, the code you posted is beyond the pale. You can*not* write code like this, it’s completely unreadable and hence worthless. Refactor it.

Comment: oh well said, I have tried to reformat it but I had to surrender

Comment: In database i declared the column type as (Column Name→SP_Photo ,Type→Image,Allow Null→True)

Comment: I have changed the data column type from Image to Varbinary(max) but after doing that im get'in a weird error
Error Below Incorrect syntax near '~'. The identifier that starts with '? ??(????F^??? ????)?????. ? ..4 ?@?.?`? ?  1$@ ! ?  0?I? T?? ? L%c2?)=?~x?|72;? Aj?????h[ ?? ? ?????a)? ?i? ?. ?bm3' is too long. Maximum length is 128. Missing end comment mark '*/'.

Answer (score 0):

Before inserting an image.

1. Convert to byte array,i.e dim imgbyte as byte=datarow("Your Photo column")
2. Then convert/build a Memory Stream and build image for the memory stream
3. Now use the image which you have build and use it in insert query as shown below

   Dim img_b As Byte() = dr("SP_Photo")
   Dim img_stream As IO.MemoryStream
   img_stream = New IO.MemoryStream(img_b)
   Dim img As Image = Image.FromStream(img_stream)

   Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("update user_table_name set user_Photo=@image where user_ID=" & dr("SP_ID"), connstr)

   cmd.Parameters.Add("@image", SqlDbType.Image, img_b.Length).Value = img_b

   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()